# firebase checking document exists

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, discord.js

from discord js

```
client.on('message',msg => {
    if (msg.channel.type === "dm") return;
    let ticket_number = msg.channel.name.slice(5).toUpperCase();
    db.collection('tickets').doc(ticket_number).get().then((database) =>{
        if(!database.exists) return
            db.collection('tickets').doc(ticket_number).update({
                "ticket_log":`${database.data().ticket_log} \n [${msg.author.tag}] : ${msg}`
            }) 
        
    })
});
```

it keeps throwing error

F:\TP_Forum\node_modules@google-cloud\firestore\build\src\path.js:403
throw new Error(`${validate_1.invalidArgumentMessage(arg, 'resource path')} Path must be a non-empty string.`);

```
Error: Value for argument "documentPath" is not a valid resource path. Path must be a non-empty string.
    at Object.validateResourcePath (F:\TP_Forum\node_modules\@google-cloud\firestore\build\src\path.js:403:15)
    at CollectionReference.doc (F:\TP_Forum\node_modules\@google-cloud\firestore\build\src\reference.js:1988:20)
    at Client.<anonymous> (F:\TP_Forum\index.js:61:30)
    at Client.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (F:\TP_Forum\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (F:\TP_Forum\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (F:\TP_Forum\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:386:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (F:\TP_Forum\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:436:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (F:\TP_Forum\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (F:\TP_Forum\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:125:16)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's almost certainly the case that `ticket_number` is an empty string.  You should check that in your code before using the string in the path of a document.